# Brightness bug on iMac14,3 I leave to see Brightness control on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: brightness

Just one day I started computer and I leave to see brightness control and the screen looks dark, and I can't find way to revolve, I restarted.
There is a way to resolve without reinstall all programs?

[image]

Comment: `I leave to see brightness control ` -- What do you mean by that?

Comment: Did this problem occur right after a new installation? Or did it occur suddenly in an existing installation?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi On top right corner normally you find brightness control for increase or decrease of screen bright, in my case I can see that.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi This occurred suddenly in an existing installation

Comment: I tried to install ubuntu again and its work fine but when I tried to upgrade, appear alert mentioning a not correct upgrade about graphics and then I did a partial upgrade then one more time I get the same error.